# pass parameter using system command

Tags: c, parameter-passing, c++builder, system-calls

I have an executable program that runs in several pc's in a network. 
At first it gets the host name (pc-001.. pc-013 etc). Then i need to mount a network drive (server1) on even pc's and (server2) on odds one based on its host name.

My problem is that i use system call to run dos command 'net use' for example

```
system ("net use x: \\\\server1\\shares /user:username pass");
```

How can i pass a variable to username? username is the host name which i know its value and pass is the same for all computers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could build the command passed to `system` e.g. like

```
 char cmdbuf[256];
 snprintf(cmdbuf, sizeof(cmdbuf), 
          "net use x: \\\\server1\\shares /user:%s %s", 
          username, password);
 int err = system(cmdbuf);
 if (err) { fprintf(stderr, "failed to %s\n", cmdbuf); 
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }
```

Be careful about the given `username` and `password`. A `username` like  the string `"user; somenaughtycommand"` (without the quotes) will give you nightmares. Beware of [code injections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection), so test that both `username` and `password` are somehow valid, or appropriately escape them. Don't forget to test the outcome of `system` library call.

You could want to check the number of characters put in `cmdbuf` i.e. the result of [snprintf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snprintf). If it is `>= sizeof(cmdbuf)` you probably should avoid calling `system`!

Answer (score 3):

Use the [`snprintf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) to construct the command string before you use it:

```
char command[128];
snprintf(command, sizeof(command), "net use x: \\\\server1\\shares /user:%s %s",
         some_username, some_password);
system(command);
```