# how to pass a variable to command in c

Tags: c, linux, bash

I've written a C program on Linux to calculate the perimeter (I've called the perimeter variable "p") of a square from its side length ("l").
Now I want to use Espeak, a speech synthesis program on Linux to speak the result.
I've thought of using the "system" method.

For example, if I want to make Espeak speak "hello" inside my program I would do:

```
system("espeak -v it Hello");
```

Now how can I do with the perimeter?

```
system ("espeak -v it The perimeter is p");
```

doesn't work.

Comment: Probably just need to add quotes around the phrase so it is just one parameter.

Comment: possible duplicate of [pass parameter using system command](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18014626/pass-parameter-using-system-command)

Comment: @skrrgwasme loved the "removed fluff" in the edit description. It made my... 10 mintues

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could build the command like in

```
char command[128];
snprintf(command, sizeof command, "espeak -v it The perimeter is %d", p);
```

if `p` is an integer, you should change the format specifier if the type of `p` is different.

Comment: close, but OP has a variable named `p` that needs to get embedded into the string. `"espeak -v it the perimeter is %s"`

Comment: As an exercise for the reader, now make it pass "three hundred twenty". :-)

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to all!
I just solved with

```c
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char command[128];
    int p=40;
    snprintf(command, sizeof(command), "espeak -v it  \"Il perimetro è %d\"",p);
    printf("%s\n",command);
    system(command);
}
```