# How to concatenate strings

Tags: c, string, string-concatenation

when i use directory n gpg error happens: gpg: no such directory or file but it has 
i have:

```
char directory[100]="/tmp/hello.txt"
```

there is a code

```
int s = system("echo password | gpg -c --passphrase-fd 0 directory");
```

For information if I write instead of directory '/tmp/hello.txt' it will work
maybe the problem with ' '

Comment: Btw, calling external tools with `system()` is something you should avoid if possible (manageability of dependencies is problematic, a shell is forked with it, and so on). In this case, look at [GPGme](https://www.gnupg.org/(es)/related_software/gpgme/index.html), it *might* suit your needs.

Comment: also gpg might not be in your path

Comment: Don't do this on a multi user machine: Everybody will be able to read your passphrase while GnuPG is executed!

Answer (score 1):

C doesn't automatically replace occurences of an identifier with its value. The preprocessor does that, though. You could define a macro

```
#define directory "/tmp/hello.txt"
```

and then do

```
int s = system("echo password | gpg -c --passphrase-fd 0 " directory);
```

This [concatenates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10295634/c-string-concatenation-of-constants) the strings at "preprocessing time", even before compile time. Another way would be to use `strncat` to concatenate the two strings at runtime:

```
char str[128] = "echo password | gpg -c --passphrase-fd 0 ";
strncat(str, directory, sizeof(str) - strlen(str));
```

To be able to reappend the string you could store the `strlen(str)`, write a null byte to it every time and then call `strncat`:

```
void append(const char* app) {
    static const size_t len = strlen(str);

    str[len] = '\0';
    strncat(str, app, sizeof(str) - len);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but my directory depends on buffer so the directory is not constant it changes

Comment: so is there other solution]

Comment: @John You can use it: `int s = system(str);` where `str` refers to the string in my answer.

Comment: @John, please read some introductory text about C. This is not a "C interactive tutorial" site and there are plenty of resources out there ...

Answer (score 1):

this is a duplicate question from:  [pass parameter using system command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18014626/pass-parameter-using-system-command)

shows how to pass local variable contents to the system command

Here is the suggested code, Note: `username` and `password` are local variables:

```
char cmdbuf[256];
snprintf(cmdbuf, sizeof(cmdbuf), 
      "net use x: \\\\server1\\shares /user:%s %s", 
      username, password);
int err = system(cmdbuf);
if (err) 
{ 
    fprintf(stderr, "failed to %s\n", cmdbuf); 
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks the previous error fixed but another error happened sh:2 syntax '|' unexpected

Comment: suggest appending an edit to your question, showing exactly your modified code.